# Why association does not add a new record to my table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations, nested-attributes

I have 2 models: Chocolate and Kind, where chocolate class looks like:

```
class Chocolate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kinds, inverse_of: :chocolate
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kinds
```

and Kind class looks like:

```
class Kind < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chocolate
```

I have the next simple form, which contains:

```
= simple_form_for @chocolate do |ch|
  = ch.simple_fields_for :kinds, @chocolate.kinds.build(kind: 'Bitter') do |k|
    = k.input :kind
  = ch.input :netto 
  = ch.submit
```

So, when I submit my form, it adds a new record to my `chocolates` table, but it does not add a record to my `kinds` table, through associations.

In `ChocolateController` I have:

```
private
def chocolate_params
  params.require(:chocolate).permit(:netto, kinds_attributes: [:kind])
end
```

So, why it does not write to my table with associations? Where have I a mistake?

Comment: Can you please add the params log?

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iu7...YPw==", "kind"=>{"kind"=>"Bitter"}, "chocolate"=>{"netto"=>"500 gr"}, "commit"=>"Create Chocolate"}` @prakashS please

Comment: You are permitting `kinds_attributes` where `kind` is in the actual parameters. Meaning you won't get the attribute for a new Kind.

Comment: Your problem is that your nested model isn't being nested in the form correctly. You need to change `simple_fields_for :kinds`, maybe to `ch.simple_fields_for :kinds`. I haven't used simple_form before, but that's how it would be done using standard Rails form helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use nested models with simple form: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

so, you need something like:

```
= simple_form_for @chocolate do |ch|
  = ch.simple_fields_for :kinds ...
```

Comment: thank you! That was useful! I fixed that, but nothing again =/